# Where will I unregister NSNotification?

Tags: ios, ios5, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I often registered NSNotification in a viewDidLoad and unregistered in a dealloc. We don't have dealloc in ios 5. Where will I unregister NSNotification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use dealloc in ARC (I assume this is what you mean by iOS 5) - just define the method as before. Just don't call [super dealloc].

```
- (void) dealloc {
   // unregister and clean up.
   // NO SUPER!
}
```

I use this pattern a lot - especially when checking for leaks it's handy to put an NSLog in there.

Comment: also, you should unregister for all notifications in the viewDidUnload, since you registering again in the viewDidLoad there will be no problem.